# What's the best way to wrap an XPath language/interface over POJOs?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, jxpath

I'd like to expose a tree of POJOs via a simple "XPath" like language so that users can do something like `/purchaseOrder/location[@city = 'Mountain View']`?

Comment: Please give a little more detail on what you're trying to do. How would the user interact with your system? Would you have POJO's loaded in your program and then let the user "query" them?

Comment: Yes, the POJOs are pre-existing instances and loaded. However, there could be cases where 1 POJO's fields can get copied to another via XPath.

Answer (score 4):

I've looked at [Apache JXpath](http://commons.apache.org/jxpath/index.html) which seems to be pretty decent and is somewhat maintained. I don't know how fast it is though.

I've also seen [Jaxen](http://jaxen.codehaus.org/faq.html) which requires some extra work by the user as described [here](http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2009/04/xpath-over-html-using-jericho-and-jaxen.html) and by reading [PMD's soure code](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/xpathruletutorial.html). But Jaxen seems to have been [abandoned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908762/is-jaxen-still-actively-supported-developed) by its authors. Also, I don't know what version of XPath is supported here.

Are there others?

Answer (score 2):

If your POJOs are mapped to XML via JAXB metadata, then you could wrap the root object in an instance of [`javax.xml.bind.util.JAXBSource`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/util/JAXBSource.html) and use the [`javax.xml.xpath`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html) APIs to issue XPath queries against it.

Comment: That does not work. `JAXBSource source = new JAXBSource(jaxbContext, parent);
 Object result = expr.evaluate(source.getInputSource());` throws an error saying MalformedUrlException because the getInputSource() is all nulls

Comment: I found out the proper way to do this using JAXB objects - http://www.devguli.com/blog/eng/jaxb-binder-and-xpath/

Comment: Or this http://jarfiller.com/guide/jaxb/xpath.xhtml. But you will find that JXPath is way faster