# Modify XPath expressions via Java?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have XPath expressions of the type `//*[@id='test-id' and @some-other-attribute='some-value’]`. I want to convert it into `//*[@resourceId='android:id/test-id' and @some-other-attribute='some-value’]`.

I can't seem to find any library function to do that. I don't want to resort to regex find and replace on the string - looking for a structured way to do it. Appreciate any pointer.

NOTE: I am not looking to evaluate an XPath expression against an XML file. I am looking to modify the XPath expression itself, without resorting to string replace.

**Update:**

Following kjhughes@ recommendation, I got to the following code to get a parse tree of the xpath expression.

```
Processor proc = new Processor(false);
XPathCompiler p = new XPathCompiler(proc);
XPathExecutable exec = p.compile("//*[@id='test-id' and @some-other-attribute='some-value']");
exec.getUnderlyingExpression().getInternalExpression().explain(new StandardLogger());
```

This produces:

```
<filterExpression>
   <slash simple-step="true">
      <root/>
      <axis name="descendant" nodeTest="element()"/>
   </slash>
   <operator op="and">
      <operator op="=" cardinality="one-to-one">
         <data>
            <axis name="attribute" nodeTest="attribute(Q{}id)"/>
         </data>
         <literal value="test-id" type="xs:string"/>
      </operator>
      <operator op="=" cardinality="one-to-one">
         <data>
            <axis name="attribute" nodeTest="attribute(Q{}some-other-attribute)"/>
         </data>
         <literal value="some-value" type="xs:string"/>
      </operator>
   </operator>
</filterExpression>
```

Is my only option to parse the XML nodes and recompose the expression? Or is there a shorter way that I am missing?

(I still have to figure out if converting the XML back to Xpath expression is trivial or if it will involve any trickery.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rewrite an XPath expression programatically then you would  need to look into XPath parsers. See https://www.w3.org/2002/11/xquery-xpath-applets/xpathApplet.html for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two libraries that you can use to parse XPath expressions:

1. Saxon's [net.sf.saxon.s9api.XPathCompiler](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XPathCompiler.html).  You might also want to experiment with the [explain() interface](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/expr/Expression.html) on compiled XPaths.
2. [The Jaxen XPath Engine for Java](https://github.com/jaxen-xpath/jaxen).  Note, however, that Jaxen's support/stability has [vacillated over time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908762/is-jaxen-still-actively-supported-developed).

Given a choice, I'd develop against Saxonica's library.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I checked Saxonica and got to the explain() part - but need some help moving forward. Updated my question as I need to post formatted code.